# No cached version of gradle available for offline mode

Tags: android, caching, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have no Internet connection at all in my development environment, even temporary Internet is not an option.

I have received Android project, but I cannot compile it at all.

I get the following message:

"No cached version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2` available for offline mode"

Can I provide the dependencies/caches/etc manually?

Comment: You have to sync the project at least once. Android studio has to download and then cache the dependencies for the modules to work.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That is not an option. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION**

Simply Go in :

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Unchecked
>   Offline Mode

Now Run your app in device if it's 1st time successfully installed then You go in Setting same as above path

AND Checked **Offline Mode**

Now your Offline Mode working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Gradle needs to download the dependencies from the declared repositories once to have them in its cache and then being able to use those cached versions in offline mode.

If that is not an option, you can instead build a local repository with the needed dependencies and write a Gradle init script that replaces all declared repositories with your local repository, then Gradle can take the dependencies from your local repository.

Comment: Any guide? Tutorial?