# No Cached Version Gradle Plugin Available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I haven't used Android Studio in a while, but decided to update everything and create a new project and I get the above error, if I go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle.

There's no option to 'Work Offline' as suggested here among other places [No cached version of gradle available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958541/no-cached-version-of-gradle-available-for-offline-mode)

I've also used the 'Command Shift A' and searched for 'Offline' and I get nothing. Anyway to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Android Studio 3.6 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3.6-gradle-offline-ui):

> To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select **View > Tool Windows > Gradle** from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the **Gradle** window, click **Toggle Offline Mode**

Answer (score 12):

To Enable or Disable Gradle Offline Mode In Android Studio 3.6.1 please see in picture below :
[image]

```
or
```

Try View ➡️ Tool Windows ➡️ Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode

```
or
```

If you want demo video so please have a look on : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50WxM7mu6pg

Answer (score 5):

To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode,  View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode

you can also watch this video https://youtu.be/lbCM8N8ItRI

Answer (score 2):

The toggle button always says - 'Toggle Offline Mode' and never changes to 'Toggle Online Mode' How will I know whether gradle sync will run in offline mode or online mode?

Comment: If toggle button is in normal state - offline mode is disabled, otherwise (if button is highlighted) - offline mode is enabled.