# error while building signed apk how can i solve this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

I'm a new at android studio today finished a project trying to build signed apk but getting error
I really tried hard to find reson but failing badly

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3 available for offline mode.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

and the app build section is given below, i don't know who to solve this, please give answer
also mention reason so that i can learn form it app build section is given below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.covid_19"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }}}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:1.0.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable offline mode in gradle and sync the project

Answer (score 0):

this happen because your android studio use gradle on mode offline.
please see this solutions : [No Cached Version Gradle Plugin Available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481987/no-cached-version-gradle-plugin-available-for-offline-mode)