# `no cached resource available for offline mode` when publishing to Maven Central

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, sonatype, maven-central

I've published 5 versions of my repository so far without any issues. With version 1.0.5 I'm getting an error:

> `Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToOSSRHRepository'.`
>
> > `> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'OSSRH'`
> >
> > > `> No cached resource 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/github/jspinak/brobot/1.0.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml' available for offline mode.`

The only help I've found online is to toggle the offline mode in Gradle
([No Cached Version Gradle Plugin Available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481987/no-cached-version-gradle-plugin-available-for-offline-mode)),
which then produces the following error when publishing:

> `Could not GET 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/io/github/jspinak/brobot/1.0.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.`
>
> > `Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

I'm not sure if this is something I've done wrong, a Sonatype issue, a Gradle issue, an Intellij issue, or something else. I've also posted on the Sonatype message boards just in case.

In the Gradle Toolbar, there is an option *generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication*. Running this doesn't seem to change anything.

This is an open source repository and you can see the build.gradle file at
https://github.com/jspinak/brobot/blob/main/library/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when trying to publish a *snapshot* version to the staging repository, which is for *release* versions. A snapshot differs from a release version in that it can be changed. Release versions cannot be changed to give developers who are using it the security that the functionality of their code will not change due to changes in the dependencies. Snapshots can be used for testing or to provide easy access to the latest code while still in development. Any version name with "-SNAPSHOT" at the end is considered a snapshot. All other names are considered release versions.

To publish a snapshot I would need the following lines of code in my build.gradle file:
`version = '1.0.5-SNAPSHOT'`
`url = "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"`

To publish a release version, I would need the following code:
`version = '1.0.5'`
`url = "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"`